# Flutter change material3 button shape

Tags: flutter, material3

I upgraded the flutter to version `3.10` recently and set `useMaterial3: true` as its default is true.

But I cannot change the button's shape:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: FilledButton(
          style: FilledButtonTheme.of(context).style?.copyWith(
                  shape: const MaterialStatePropertyAll<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                      RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
              ))),
          onPressed: () {},
          child: const Text("Click"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want a square button (or any customized border), but every time the result is the same:
[image]

**Update:** without adding shape to button, it is the same as screen shot above.

Comment: Why without adding shape?

Answer (score 1):

So to need a square button you just remove the shape property of the button it can result in shard edged button

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just override the border of the filled Button for all states.

```
FilledButtonThemeData(
          style: ButtonStyle(
            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
              const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius:
                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```